# Is trigger action via props asyncrounous ?

Tags: reactjs

say the code below:

```
this.props.getRemoteUserId()
this.props.getRemotePrice()
```

the first function will get the userId and then with that Id I can fetch the new price. My question is : is `this.props.getRemotePrice()` fired after the new userId has save to the store?

Comment: If you can show the code for `getRemoteUserId()` we'll be able to answer that for you.

Comment: We can never give you a complete answer because we are not aware whether it is synchronous or asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on what is inside those functions. If they are both asynchronous AJAX calls for instance, then you can never be sure which one will finish first.